# JS Split for each letter

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have string like

A203 323 B232 443 C3434 34 34 34 D443 3434 C43 34

I try to get array like:

[A203 323,B232 443,C3434 34 34 34,D443 3434,C43 34]

any ideas

I not good at all with RegExp so please help me with it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
var s = 'A203 323 B232 443 C3434 34 34 34 D443 3434 C43 34';
var r = s.split(/ (?=[A-Z])/g);
//=> ["A203 323", "B232 443", "C3434 34 34 34", "D443 3434", "C43 34"]
```